# using python "or" to filter names or orders to find all lowcase and all caps versions of the name

Tags: python, database, filter, filtering

I am new to python and am using it to filter data from the server side to be used in the front end for a graph. I need to filter orders from a given name which I can do successfully with this code :

```
def get_filteres_orders(dataset_id, order):
data = dt.get(dataset_id).aslist()
filtered_data = [x for x in data if x['PRIMARY_MNEMONIC'] == 
order ]
filtered_data.sort(key=lambda x: to_data_time(x['ORDER_DTM']), reverse=True)
return filtered_data
```

However, I need to search for both the lowercase and all caps version of the order name. For example, when I type ASPIRIN I get a separate array of orders than when I type aspirin. I have tried to add the | or operand to account for the all caps versions but it doesn't work. Here is what I have:

```
def get_filteres_orders(dataset_id, order):
data = dt.get(dataset_id).aslist()
#filtered_data = [x for x in data if x['PRIMARY_MNEMONIC'] == order ]
#filtered_data = [x for x | x.upper() for x in data if x['PRIMARY_MNEMONIC'] 
== order ] 
filtered_data = [x | x.upper() for x in data if x['PRIMARY_MNEMONIC'] == 
order ]
filtered_data.sort(key=lambda x: to_data_time(x['ORDER_DTM']), reverse=True)
return filtered_data
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?
Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "doesn't work"? What result do you get? Do you get an error? What type of data structure is `data`? Is it a list of dictionaries? A list of a custom object type?

Comment: You MUST normalized the data input. I.e. , all data must be formatted in either lower case OR upper case. That will solve your sorting problem.

Comment: @dlasalle your absolutely right "doesn't work" is a little vague. I get an internal server error (500). It says it is coming from my ajax file. I am pretty positive it is due to an error in syntax for trying to filter/my lack of python knowledge because when I resort back to the first filter function it works fine. The server is using a framework called phovea, but the data is taken from a csv file and imported from the phovea server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do `x['PRIMARY_MNEMONIC'].lower() == order.lower()` in python you use "or" not "|" and btw python have a filter function so you can do something like this also

`filter(function, iterable)`

`filter(lambda x: x['PRIMARY_MNEMONIC'].lower() == order.lower(), data)`

assuming data is a dictionary `x | x.upper()` is so weird

Comment: Hey thank you @Hamuel! I used x['PRIMARY_MNEMONIC'].upper() and got what I needed. I am not using a dictionary, I have a very long csv file of order values pulled from a health records database. Looking forward @mootmoot your totally right- reformatting the data to be uniform in the file would be the way to go about it.